# Automatically Creating and Logging-in New Customer via Email in Shopify with New Customer Account System

Tags: authentication, email, shopify, shopify-app, one-time-password

I'm currently working on a Shopify theme & custom shopify app (an API-only app), and I have a specific requirement that I'm unsure of how to implement. I'd appreciate any guidance or insights you might have.

**Objective**:

- I want to add an email input field along with a submit button inside my Shopify theme.
- Once the submit button is clicked, I'd like to check if a customer with the entered email exists.
- If the customer does NOT exist:

  - Create a new customer with the provided email.
  - Automatically log the customer in.

My question then is: **Is it possible to achieve the above using the new OTP-based account system?**

I'm aware that something similar could be achieved (sort-of) with Shopify's older account system. However, with the introduction of the new customer account system, I'm uncertain about how to go about this.

I also want to emphasize that the solution can involve calls to any shopify API, but only if the call is triggered by hitting an endpoint on a shopify using javascript embedded in the theme.

I would be grateful for any pointers, code samples, or relevant documentation links that could guide me.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!

I tried looking at the existing [customer account API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/customer), which is relatively new, but it seems geared towards headless stores, which is not our case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so not to waste any time, I am unsure of how you would be able to do it with Shopify's code system. There are some services out there that do OPT systems for your shopify users such as [miniorange][1]

As for the actual functionality, I can provide some insight of how you might do the first few things.

To check if the customer exists, you can use this:

```
fetch("/admin/api/2023-07/customers/search.json?query=email:<user_input_email>")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
   if(data.customers.length > 0) {
      // customer exists
   } else {
      // create a new customer
   }
});
```

If the customer doesn't exist, you can create one via a POST request to `/admin/api/2023-07/customers.json`:

```
const newCustomerData = {
  customer: {
    first_name: "First_Name",
    last_name: "Last_Name",
    email: "<user_input_email>",
    verified_email: true,
    send_email_invite: false,
    send_email_welcome: false
  }
};

fetch("/admin/api/2023-07/customers.json", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(newCustomerData)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
   // handle success
});
```

This might be a good start for your theme, hope this helps!
[1]: https://plugins.miniorange.com/shopify-single-sign-on-sso-for-mobile-application

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The real tough part tho is the auto-login step. We'd really like to stick with Shopify's new built-in OTP login accounts, but we also need to be able to log-in a new customer silently without them having to input the OTP. I see how your insight can be used to create the customer and check if it exists, but not how to log him in automatically browser-side afterward. Thanks!

Comment: @afjaramilg-balto i don't really think this is possible, as the whole point of OTP is to add another level of security, thus only the user will get the code. The only way around this would be if you make your own OTP system or maybe automate an account creation with your own values and sign them in then change it to their values, this could be a security risk though!